# Exchange rule regex on sender name not address

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

In Exchange 2013, is ist possible to create a Transport regex rule based on the sender name, not the sender emailaddress?

The goal is to identify fake senders, using the name field for a fake emailaddress.
Normal: "John Doe "
Bad: "trustful@mail.com "

The very goal would be to identify two @ in the Sender, an exception would be, when both are the same like
"trustful@mail.com "

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not, there's no special rule action to compare the sender name and its email address, also it's not a valuable way to prevent "fake" sender.

Instead, the **SPF record** will be used to declare and verify who can send e-mails from a given domain. Thus, we can use it to detect and prevent spoofing message.